# How to get text content from iOS screen?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

How to get the text content of screen? Both from a WebView and a Native App.

For example, from the following image, I would like to get/extract/retrieve the title and the first two paragraphs.

[image: iphone wikipedia]

[On Android this is possible using the accessibility tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909926/get-text-content-of-the-android-screen!%5Benter). But so far I haven't found how to do something like that on iOS.

I would like to know how to do this natively using `Swift / Xcode`. But if is possible with `EXPO or React Native` it would also help a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are asking is the accessibility identifier.

Under the identity inspector you can find the Accessibility section and there you have a text field for an identifier.

[image: accessibility identifier ios]

Alternatively you can set this via code

for example:

```
submitButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "submitButton"
```

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your anwser. But this is not what I mean. I've edited my question to better clarify.